# Loading dwg drawing from a local folder

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk

I have implemented forge offline viewing application.Converted files, downloaded from server are put in a folder corresponding to the viewer location under the application folder. Is it possible to load converted documents from a directory other than the the one inside the application folder?

Answer (score 0):

Forge Viewer is built from the web technologies, all model files must have to under a web server, otherwise, the viewer cannot fetch your model via [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest).

You can move all your derivative files into another directory exposed by a web server or a folder of another web application, it's not necessary to put them inside the same application.